# Calling Jquery click event with AJAX POST method after triggering already jquery click event in codeigniter framewormk

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter, dropdown

I want to filter brand wise coupons from two dropdowns which are coming from database. when I select/click on first dropdown to select brand name than it automatically select coupons which are registered for selected brand in 1st  dropdown using AJAX and JQUERY. I did all but not working.

I'm new in **CodeIgniter**. Ajax isn't calling controller function even though everything is correct please help. thanks in advance

```html
<!-- script code for two dropdown coming from database in view file -->
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $(document).on('click', '.add', function() {
           var html = '';
           html += '<tr>';
           html += `<td>
                       <select name="Brand_name[]" id="brand1" class="form-control item_unit">
                           <option value="">Select Brand Name</option>

                           <?php
                               if (isset($bdata) && !empty($bdata)) {
                                   foreach ($bdata as $brand) {
                                       echo '<option value="'.$brand->userId.'" >'.$brand->name.'</option>';
                                   }
                               }
                           ?>
                       </select>`;

           html += `<td>
                       <select name="item_unit[]" id="coupon_n" class="form-control item_unit">
                           <option value="">Select Coupon Name</option>   

                           <?php
                               if (isset($udata) && !empty($udata)) {
                                   foreach ($udata as $coupon) {
                                       echo '<option value="'.$coupon->couponid.'" >'.$coupon->offer_name.'</option>';
                                   }
                               }
                           ?> 
                       </select>`;
       });
   });
</script>
```

```html
<!-- Again jQuery code for brand wise coupon filtering for passed brand_id when I clicked on 1st dropdown so that automatically next dropdown (coupons register for perticular  brand)work -->
<script>
    $("body").on('click', '#brand1', function() {
        var brand_id = $(this).val();
        console.log(brand_id);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '<?php echo base_url('index.php/admin/Package_controller/getCoupons');?>',
            data: {
                brand_id: brand_id
            },
            // dataType: "dataType",
            success: function(response) {
                $("#coupon_n").html();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

```php
//controller function to get coupon for selected brand in 1st drop down passed brand id using ajax post method and URL
public function getCoupons()
{
    $admin_id=$_POST['brand_id'];
    $coupons=$this->Add_Packagemodel->fetch_coupon_Details($admin_id);
    $data['coupons']=$coupons;
    $this->load->view('admin/package/addpackage', $data);
}

//model function for filtering coupons after selecting brand id from 1st dropdown
public function fetch_coupon_Details()
{
    $c_result=$this->db->select('offer_name')->from('coupon_managment')->get();

    if ($c_result->num_rows()) 
    {
        return $c_result;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of hierarchy, first you populate the brand filter normally using `php` then `onchange` event do the `ajax` call to controller, do `echo json_encode($couponsBasedOnBrand);` from controller, the rest work is done in `js`.

```js
function getCouponByBrand(brand_id,base_url){
  url_final = base_url+"/getCouponByBrand"; //your url; goes to controller and get coupons by brand
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url_final,
     data: {brand_id : brand_id},
     dataType: "text",
     cache:false,
     success:
      function(data){
        $('#coupon_id').css('display', 'block');
        $('#coupon_id').html('<option value="">Select Coupon</option>');
          var dataObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          if(dataObj){
            $(dataObj).each(function(){
              var option = $('<option />');
              option.attr('value', this.id).text(this.name);
              $('#coupon_id').append(option);
            });
          }else{
            $('#coupon_id').html('<option value="">Coupons are not available</option>');
          }
        }
      });
 return false;
}
```

```html
    <select name="brand_id" id="brand_id"
      onchange="getCouponByBrand(this.value,'<?php echo base_url();?>')" style="display:block;">
      <option value="">Select Brand</option>
      <?php 
      if (isset($bdata) && !empty($bdata)) {
         foreach ($bdata as $brand) {
             echo '<option value="'.$brand->userId.'" >'.$brand->name.'</option>';
         }
      }
      ?>
    </select>

    <select name="coupon_id" id="coupon_id">
      <option value="">Select Coupon</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: many many thanks for your reply but I would like to add my project requirement is like on a click event we are adding new rows for coupons (since number of coupons are dynamic i.e we don't know how many coupons will be added by user/operator) Therefore JQuery function is calling on click add new coupon button than again one more JQuery function needed to call using ajax to filter brand wise coupon so please provide the solution in terms of two JQuery function calling one after another.

Comment: sorry, not much clear to me. can you share some image of your requirement